# Beautiful Soup Extract Table Inforamtion

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to beautiful soup and I am trying to pull data from [this](https://rotogrinders.com/game-stats/nba-player?site=fanduel&range=4weeks) website.

```
import bs4
import requests as re
import pandas as pd

class roto_PlayerStats:

    class roto_Player:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = ""
            self.team = ""
            self.pos = ""
            self.salary = 0
            self.minutes = 0
            self.reb = 0
            self.ast = 0
            self.stl = 0
            self.blk = 0
            self.to = 0
            self.pts = 0
            self.usg = 0
            self.fpts = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.players =[]

    def load-data(self):
        response = re.get("https://rotogrinders.com/game-stats/nba-player?site=draftkings&range=season")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        for x in soup.find_all('"id'):

            #code to load the individual data?
```

The data from the is in an array structured like the one below. Is this the right approach to loading individual player data?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var data = [{"id":915,"player":"J.R. Smith","team":"CLE","pos":"SHW","salary":null,"opp":"N\/A","gp":8,"min":"150.00","fgm":18,"fga":51,"ftm":8,"fta":8,"3pm":9,"3pa":27,"reb":13,"ast":13,"stl":10,"blk":2,"to":9,"pts":53,"usg":"18.08","pace":64,"fpts":"115.10"}, {}...]
```

NEW FUNCTION for a different webpage from the same domain

```
class grinder_Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.gp = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.reb = 0
        self.ast = 0
        self.stl = 0
        self.blk = 0
        self.to = 0
        self.pts = 0
        self.pace = 0
        self.fpts = 0

class grinder_TeamStats:

    def __init__(self):
        self.teams = []

        response = requests.get("https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings&range=season")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        proj_stats = soup.find('section', {'class': 'pag bdy'})
        script = proj_stats.find('script')
        data = re.search(r"data\s*=\s*(.*);", script.text).group(1)
        stats = json.loads(data)

        for team in stats:
            # do x

        print ("finished")
```

I get an error on this line

```
data = re.search(r"data\s*=\s*(.*);", script.text).group(1)
```

saying

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I'm not sure why this is because then i print the script and the script.text variables for both links, they have very similar outputs.

Comment: Do the values you observe in the JSON string in the script match up with what is on the page?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the response is in a JavaScript `<script>` tag. One option to load the data could be to use `regex` to find the `var data` in the script and load it into a `json` object:

```
import bs4
import requests     
import pandas as pd
import re

proj_stats = soup.find('div', {'id': 'proj-stats'})
script = proj_stats.find('script')
data = re.search(r"data\s*=\s*(.*);", script.text).group(1)
stats = json.loads(data)
```

Now you have a list of dictionaries containing stats of each player that you can store into your player class:

```
$ print(stats)

[{u'gp': 8, u'pos': u'SHW', u'player': u'J.R. Smith', u'pts': 53, u'id': 915, u'usg': u'18.08', u'min': u'150.00', u'fta': 8, u'to': 9, u'blk': 2, u'reb': 13, u'ftm': 8, u'opp': u'N/A', u'ast': 13, u'fgm': 18, u'3pm': 9, u'3pa': 27, u'fga': 51, u'salary': None, u'fpts': u'117.25', u'stl': 10, u'pace': 64, u'team': u'CLE'}, ...]
```

Note: do not `import requests as re` as `re` will override the `re` regex module  import.

Comment: I get an error on the line data = re.search("var data\s*=\s*(.*);", script.text).group(1)
               AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'search'

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Sorry about that, I forgot to mention to add `import re` to the script. but your import `import requests as re` will over-write that, so just use `import requests` and `response = requests.get()`. Please replace your import statements with the one's I've added to the answer. And reference `requests` module as `requests` not `re`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the imports and it works. Could you explain the variables proj_stats, script, and data more in-depth please?

Comment: I'm trying to run the same function for a similar site here https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings&range=season. The data is loaded i to the html page in the same way.

Comment: I get this: object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: the variables p`roj_stats`, `script`, and `data` are just variable names that I made up to refer to levels of data that I was parsing. You could combine them all into one variable, but I separated them into 3 levels. `proj-stats` gets all the content we need to parse, then inside `proj-stats` we get the javascript `<script>` tag contents saved into a variable named `script`, then from this content we extract only the `var data` javascript content that contains the list.

Comment: Gotcah. I'm going to edit my original post, but would you mind helping me see why my next example doesn't work for a different website

Comment: Yes it your next example contains different javascript. Did you look at the same function in your next example? The example in the question, as you noted, defines the data array as `var data = [{"id":915,"player"...`.., but your next example defines the same data as `data = [{"team":"Boston Celtics","abbr"` without `var`, and they removed the terminating semicolon `;` from the script. So basically to cover any example, just replace the search with simply `data` as `re.search(r"data\s*=\s*(.*);"` I've updated the answer to work with both examples. Please run the script again on both examples.

Answer (score 0):

the script doesn't have semicolon `;` remove it from regex, you can cut BeautifulSoup and use `re` directly

```
response = requests.get("https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings&range=season")
data = re.search(r"data\s*=\s*(.*)", response.content).group(1)
stats = json.loads(data)
```